# systemd: Scope vs Service

Tags: service, systemd, scope

The [man page for scope](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.scope.html) says:

> Unlike service units, scope units manage externally created processes,
>   and do not fork off processes on its own.

On my RHEL server, I can see that gdm belongs to the gdm service. So does its child, *gdm-simple-slave*. *gdm-simple-slave* has created *gdm-session-worker*, but this process belongs to a scope, not the gdm service.

In light of this, **what does "*externally created process*" mean, and what is the difference between a service and a scope?**

For those readers who prefer code:

```
# systemctl status gdm
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-03-04 16:27:45 EST; 1 day 3h ago
  Process: 1330 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c TERM=linux /usr/bin/clear > /dev/tty1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1307 (gdm)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           ├─1307 /usr/sbin/gdm
           ├─1331 /usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave --display-i...
           └─1364 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -background none -verbos...
# ps -ef|grep 1331
root      1331  1307  0 Mar04 ?    00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-simple-slave...
root      2032  1331  0 Mar04 ?    00:00:00 gdm-session-worker ...
# systemctl status 2032
session-38.scope - Session 38 of user root
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/session-38.scope; static)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/session-38.scope.d
           └─90-After-systemd-logind\x2eservice.conf, 90-After-systemd-user-sessions\x2eservice.conf, 90-Description.conf, 90-SendSIGHUP.conf, 90-Slice.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-03-04 21:12:08 EST; 22h ago
```

Answer (score 2):

An externally created process is a process that was spawned by a process other than the systemd daemon running as PID 1.

For both a scope and a service, systemd will create the cgroups to allow you to manage the processes inside it as a whole. (For example, you can use `systemctl stop` to stop a scope and kill all processes inside it.)

But with a service, systemd has the command-line to run and will run it in that environment.

With gdm-session-worker, for instance, that is not really possible, since it's supposed to be spawn by gdm-simple-slave... So in order to still keep a separate session for each gdm-session-worker, gdm will still communicate with systemd to ask it to create a new scope and then create that gdm-session-worker in that new scope.

I hope this answers your question... You have already found the [systemd scope man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.scope.html) page. If you want a more technical deep dive onto the API you might want to look into the [New Control Group Interfaces](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/), though perhaps an easier way to try it is using the [`systemd-run --scope` command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html).

Comment: Thanks Filipe. I am sorry but I am still missing something.

`gdm-simple-slave` is created by the `gdm` process, not by `systemd`. According to your definition, it should then be an external process. Why is it a member of the gdm service, then?

On the other hand, the child of `gdm-simple-slave` **is** considered external.

So, while I now understand the purpose of services and scopes, I continue to be confused.

Comment: @berndbausch Sorry, I meant gdm-session-worker is created by gdm-simple-slave (not systemd) so gdm-session-worker **is** an external process. Then gdm-simple-slave asks systemd to add it to the scope of the user session. While gdm-simple-slave is not itself started by systemd, it belongs to a service that was started when systemd spawned a process (gdm.) I guess the difference is how transitions are made, gdm-session-worker process was first created and then moved to a scope. Starting a service will always spawn a process from it.

Comment: Leaves the question open: [What is the difference between a slice and a scope?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688298/what-is-the-difference-between-a-systemd-scope-and-a-systemd-slice)